# Is std::format going to work with things like ICU UnicodeString?

Tags: c++, unicode, fmt, stdformat

Rather than a long preamble, here is my core question, up front. The paragraphs below explain in more detail.

Is there a template parameter in [`std::format`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format) (or [`fmt`](https://fmt.dev/latest/index.html)) that will allow me to format into ICU [`UnicodeStrings`](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu-docs/apidoc/released/icu4c/classicu_1_1UnicodeString.html)?, or perhaps into something like `char16_t[]` or `std::basic_string<char16_t>`, while using a unicode library to deal with things like encoding and grapheme clusters?

**More Explanation, Background**

I see the C++20 standard has this [`std::format`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format) library component for formatting strings. (It's late in 2022 and I still can't use it my compiler (clang from Xcode 14), and I'm curious about the cause of the delay, but that's another question.)

I've been using this [fmt](https://fmt.dev/latest/index.html) library, which looks like a simpler preview of the official one.

```cpp
int x = 10;
fmt::print("x is {}", x);
```

I've also been using ICU's [UnicodeString](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu-docs/apidoc/released/icu4c/classicu_1_1UnicodeString.html) class. It lets me correctly handle all languages and character types, from ASCII to Chinese characters to emojis.

I don't expect the `fmt` library to aware of Unicode out of the box. That would require that it build and link with ICU, or something like it. Here's an example of how it's not:

```cpp
void testFormatUnicodeWidth() {
    // Two ways to write the Spanish word "está". 
    char *s1 = "est\u00E1";  // U+00E1 : Latin small letter A with acute
    char *s2 = "esta\u0301"; // U+0301 : Combining acute accent
    fmt::print("s1 = {}, length = {}\n", s1, strlen(s1));
    fmt::print("s2 = {}, length = {}\n", s2, strlen(s2));
    fmt::print("|{:8}|\n", s1);
    fmt::print("|{:8}|\n", s2);
}
```

That prints:

```
s1 = está, length = 5
s2 = está, length = 6
|está    |
|está   |
```

To make that width specifier work the way I want, to look nice on the screen, I could use ICU's classes, which can iterate over the visible characters ("grapheme clusters") of a string.

I don't expect `std::format` to *require* Unicode either. From what I can tell the C++ standard people create things that can run on small embedded devices. That's cool. But I'm asking if there will also be a way for me to integrate the two, so that I don't have a split world, between:

1. C++'s strings and format.
2. ICU strings if I want things to look right on screen.

Comment: `std::format()` only supports `char` (`std::string`) and `wchar_t` (`std::wstring`) data.

Comment: Interesting. Some of the other types in the library, like `basic_format_context`, have a template argument for the character type.

Comment: Yes, but that does not mean it is specialized for `char16_t`/`char32_t`, though. In fact, it is not, it is only specialized for `char`/`wchar_t` only. Most things in the standard library that deal with text are like that. There is actually very little support for `char16_t`/`char32_t` in the standard library.

Comment: I just found this. https://lists.isocpp.org/mailman/listinfo.cgi/sg16  It looks like people are actively working on it, which I'm happy to see. There a link to github there with more info, papers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

{fmt} doesn't support ICU `UnicodeString` directly but you can easily write your own formatting function that does. For example:

```
#include <fmt/xchar.h>
#include <unistr.h>

template <typename... T>
auto format(fmt::wformat_string<T...> fmt, T&&... args) -> UnicodeString {
  auto s = fmt::format(fmt, std::forward<T>(args)...);
  return {s.data(), s.size()};
}

int main() {
  UnicodeString s = format(L"The answer is {}.", 42);
}
```

Note that {fmt} supports Unicode but width estimation works on code points (like Python's `str.format`) instead of grapheme clusters at the moment. It will be addressed in one of the future releases.

Comment: That doesn't compile for me. I think because wchar_t is 32 bits on my platfrom. Is it 16 on yours?

Comment: This is just an example based on https://unicode-org.github.io/icu-docs/apidoc/released/icu4c/classicu_1_1UnicodeString.html#a16a50d4b0452adbbf960d63059362f07. You could use `char16_t` instead by replacing `fmt::wformat_string<T...>` with `fmt::basic_string_view<char16_t>` and `L"..."` with `u"..."`.

Comment: Cool, that works. One more followup question... is there a way to define a formatter specialization to allow `std::string` or `std::u8string` as args, without getting the "Mixing character types is disallowed." error? Eg, `format(u"{}", utf8Str)`. I tried defining a specialization like `template <> struct fmt::formatter<std::u8string, char16_t>` but it seems to have no effect.

Comment: {fmt} disallows implicit mixing code unit types because the latter involves transcoding. You can do it by providing a formatter for a wrapper type that will make transcoding explicit.